# ASP.NET MVC site as a virtual directory under Web Pages site?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, deployment

I have a main site, `example.com`, implemented in ASP.NET Web Pages and deployed on Azure Websites. I then have another site which is implemented in ASP.NET MVC which I'd like to deploy as `example.com/subsite`. I have created a virtual directory using the Azure Portal but when I deploy my files there, I get this very nasty error:

> An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.

I don't get any additional info, there is no YSOD, there are no failed request tracing logs when I enable them, just nothing.

I'm just guessing but probably my `web.config`s are somehow colliding. For example, under some circumstances, my request to `/subsite/something` gets caught by HTTP 500 error handler in the super site.

I need some very general advice here; is it at all possible to deploy two ASP.NET apps with their own web.config's in the same site, just using the virtual directories? If it is possible, are there some typical gotchas that I am possibly falling for?

Comment: When you get that message, it usually means that you hit an error and so it tried to serve your error page, but then it hit an another error page. That message is displayed instead of going into an endless loop. If I were you I'd check how to view the error logs for an Azure site (I'm not familiar enough with it to explain how) rather than assuming it's the web.config's colliding, through that may end up being the case.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve similar creating a virtual application inside a wordpress website. In my case, I've put the following configuration in wordpress's web.config :

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
      <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```